# Rocket.Chat SDK not receiving reaction events

Tags: java, kotlin, rocket.chat

I'm trying to make a service on kotlin, which will charge some currency to users in the rocket chat channel, under whose messages a reaction will be placed: f.e. 1 unit of currency for each reaction. I am using Rocket.Chat.Kotlin.SDK to receive events from a Rocket using a RocketChatClient. I tried to send messages, set reactions and see what appears in the service logs. I noticed that the event with the setting of the reaction comes only if the reaction was set to the last message in the channel.
Is there some way to get information about all new reactions to messages in a channel?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.